# Define a setter in a class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have a class that takes a large dict and initialize it. I have a getter that allows me to access the objects of my tmp_dict. I have also tried to write a setter to change the values of a variable, but seems it is returning `None`. My question if how can I set a setter to as well to change the values?

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, tmp_dict):
        self.vals = tmp_dict
   
    @property
    def get(self, var):
        return self.vals.get(var)

    @get.setter
    def set_val(self, var, new_val):
        self.vals[var] = new_val


tmp_dict = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 1, "val100":1}

obj = MyClass(tmp_dict)
print(obj.get("val1"))
obj.set_val("val1", 100)
print(obj.get("val1"))
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
```

Comment: Functions without a `return` will give `None` by default. You might try not printing `set` but set on its own line, then print the `get` after the set.

Comment: The setter looks like it will succeed. You just aren't returning anything from it, so `None` is automatically returned.

Comment: Thanks all- My bad.  But the way I defined the setter is OK or there is a better way?

Comment: The best way is to use the class `property` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: It's normal for a setter to return None, and to rely exclusively on the getter to actually get the value.

Comment: This setter looks like it will work, just probably the `None` output confusing you. You could make the setter return `new_val` after it succeeds.

Comment: If you add another get after the set you will see that it did actually set it. VinitiumDust is correct...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Per @MannyC suggestion, I tried to use the getting/setting the values inside the dictionary using class property for the above example and I keep getting this error: TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
I have updated my code above.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that `obj.get("val1")` could have worked one time, but produced a parameter count error the next time - I'm pretty sure that something happened between those two lines that you aren't showing us.  Something along the lines of `obj = MyClass`, perhaps (changing `obj` from an instance to the class itself).

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to use properties. If you define a property `getx(self)` you access its value by `obj.getx`. What you have is different, you just want to define a method that gets and sets dictionary values, which can be done without the decorator. Could you perhaps give us a bit more context to understand what it is that you need to achieve with your code?

Comment: To understand what's going on, the decorator under the hood redefines `get = property(get)` which is a method with only one argument (self). Thus `obj.get('val')` translates into `property(get)(obj)('val')` the leftmost piece then evaluates to `obj.get()('val')`, hence the `TypeError`

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the goal of OP. The class [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) is well suited for getting and setting properties while keeping the attributes hidden to the user. This is needed for protecting some internal variables or possibly for having side effects when values are got or set.

What I missed from the post was the word "large." If each object is initialized with a large dict, it's probably best to leave it be and define some helper functions to retrieve and set keys.

What's even better is to override the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method, which is called whenever an attribute lookup fails and the [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) method, which is called at attribute sets.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, tmp_dict):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_vals', tmp_dict)
        self.other_attr = 1234
    
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._vals[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(f"'MyClass' object has no attribute '{name}'")
            
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        if hasattr(self, '_vals') and name in self._vals.keys():
            self._vals[name] = val
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, val)
```

Then you can access the key `val1` with the usual syntax, as well as other attributes

```py
>>> tmp_dict = {"val1": 1, "val2": 2, "val3": 1, "val100": 123}
>>> obj = MyClass(tmp_dict)
>>> obj.val1
1
>>> obj.other_attr
1234
```

And you can also set them

```
>>> obj.val2 = 90
>>> obj.val2
90
```

Notice that now you can really pretend that `val1` is an attribute, which gets rid of that cumbersome `get('val1')` or `set('val2', 90)`.

Two remarks:

1. The ugly `object.__setattr__(self, name, val)` is needed to avoid infinite loops that call `__setattr__` over and over
2. I added an underscore to the attribute `_val`. This has no syntactic meaning in Python, but it serves to signal to your users that `_val` is an internal attribute and it should be interacted with only through the provided object methods.

---

**Edit**: I realized later that the `__setattr__` method performs two key lookups: one to tell whether an attribute exists and one to set it if it does. This may be unnecessarily slow so take this answer with the necessary precautions.